# jQuery UI autocomplete refresh data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I use jQuery ui autocomplete feature.

```
var colors;

$(document).ready(function(){
        loadColors();
        $('#empf').autocomplete(colors);
}

function loadColors(){
 colors = new Array(getNumColor());
//in a loop save the colors to array using colors[i] = ...
}

function addColor(){
    ...
    color[n] = color;
}
```

When the user enters new color it is saved to the color array. I switch to the autocomplete form but the entered data is not aviable until I refresh the page.

Any ideas how to make the new color avialable for autocomplete?

Comment: Be sure to post your *actual* code in questions...there are quite a few errors in the code you posted, the the question is phrased like it *is* working, so I'm attributing that to different code in the question, please comment on the answer if I've misunderstood and it's *not* currently working.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you update the color, you need to also update the [source that autocomplete uses](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source), like this:

```
function addColor() {
    // Update colors.
    $('#empf').autocomplete("setOptions", { source: colors });

    // Try "option" for older versions (if "setOptions" does not work).
}
```

[Here's a sample demo doing this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/aKaK4/), adding a color and updating the autocomplete source once a second.

Comment: I use autcomplete but with a callback function for the 'select' event. What about doing this but not re-setting the callback function? Would the callback event still work or it would disappear?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried Nick Craver's solution, which looks completely logical. Maybe, it is because I am using a URL string rather than an array as the 'source'. Unfortunately his solution does not do a live refresh for the ajax data returned. In order to refresh an ajax data source, I found that the following works:

```
element.autocomplete("option","source",url);
element.autocomplete("search");
```

I think the 'search' method is required for string or ajax URL source types.