# jQuery UI autocomplete filter data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am new to jquery and I was assigned to filter out the list once the item is already selected. There are 3 textboxes that uses the autocomplete.

source: apple, orange, mango

textbox 1 = apple
textbox 2 = apple should be filtered out in the list. it should only display orange and mango.

I was able to filter the source but the list still display the item. But the source gets updated once I refresh the page. I have found this question, here's [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699307/jquery-ui-autocomplete-refresh-data) but in my case instead of adding, i wanted to filter it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!
Zel

Comment: Might be worth posting what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1):

What i would do... Pass the value of the first textbox back to the server (& vice versa for each auto complete)

You could try something like this.

**JQuery**

```
$('#auto2_id').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'some_url/SomeAction',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        term: request.term,
                        filter: $('#auto1_id').val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        //do something
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

**server side** 
(not sure what language you're using.
but in c#  (rough code sample))

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(string term, string filter)
{
  var data = _repo.GetAllCached().Where(o => o.Text != filter && o.Text.Contains(term));
  return Json(data , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On each textbox changed event, you will have to remove that item from the list and recall the function (from the plugin). You must have been calling all of the three functions at once.