# jQuery autocomplete does not work when using remote source

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="shop-id">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#shop-id" ).autocomplete({
        source: "/ticket/get_sids",
        select: function(event, ui){
          //...
        }
    });
```

});

There is a strange autocomplete issue. If I declare the source with a static variable like this

```
    var data = ["0200","0032"];

    $( "#shop-id" ).autocomplete({
        source: "/ticket/get_sids"
    });
```

everything is like expected.

But with the dynamic source url the autocomplete does not seem to filter the search. It's like no matter what I input as search text, autocomplete opens the entire source without filtering. E.g. I type a "g" and it opens 0200, 0032 but it shouldn't because "g" does not match anything in the source.

The dynamic source returns pure json like: `["0200","0032"]`. It's a php page:

```
return new Response(json_encode($data));
```

which returns

```
["0200","0032"]
```

in the browser window.

Environment: jQuery 1.7.2 jQuery-Ui 1.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the data parameter which you'll be using to send back the filter value... if that makes any sense. So you'd need to implement some form of server side filtering before returning the response data

*" I type a "g" and it opens 0200, 0032 but it shouldn't because "g" does not match anything in the source."*

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "#shop-id" ).autocomplete({
        source: "/ticket/get_sids",
        select: function(event, ui){
          //...
        },
       data: { term: request.term   }  //"term" could be anything, based on parameters your server side method expects
        //...
     })
 });
```

I've answered a question similar to this before. hope this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11930525/1105314

Answer (score 1):

> When a String is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead the request parameter "term" gets added to the URL, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results[.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)